# Usefulness of the meta tags

Tags: html, search

I know that the following meta tag is necessary to determine the codifiying of the html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

But I don't see the meaning of implementing the following meta tags, because I have heard that google will not use their content for their search results:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="some keywords" />
<meta name="description" content="description of the page" />
<meta name="author" content="the author of the page" />
<meta name="generator" content="the programm that has wrote the code" />
```

Therefore, my question is what is the purpose of the last aforementioned meta tags if google will not use them anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keywords might still be used by some other search engines, but their usefulness is very limited.

Description shows up under the list of returned search results for Google and others, so include it.

Some other search engines might use author and generator, but I am not certain.

Answer (score 2):

That's not completely true. Google does not incorporate meta tags and their content in formulating their **web rankings**. However, the description (for example) will still be used when the site shows up on the search results.

More information from Google Search Rankings Quality Leader (Matt Cutts) here: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html

Answer (score 0):

Google may not use metatags--it uses pageranks (i.e. it examines how many pages link to a specific page do determine it's usefulness.)

But that's how google works, other search engines--specifically older ones--still look at metatags to classify the contents page.